# Convert multiple columns in pyspark dataframe into one dictionary

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have created a PySpark DataFrame like this one:
'''

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('v', 3, 'a'),
    ('d', 2, 'b'),
    ('q', 9, 'c')],
    ["c1", "c2", "c3"]
)

df.show()

c1  | c2 | c3
v   |  3 | a
d   |  2 | b
q   |  9 | c
```

I want to create a new column like this:

```
+--------------------------+
|           c4             |
+--------------------------+
|{"c1":"v","c2":3,"c3":"a"}|
|{"c1":"d","c2":2,"c3":"b"}|
|{"c1":"q","c2":9,"c3":"c"}|
+--------------------------+
```

I want `c4` to be in type of `MapType`, not `StringType`
Also, I want to keep the type of values as it is. (keep 3,2 and 9 as integers, not String)

Answer (score 4):

Use `struct` + `to_json` like this if you want to get JSON strings:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = df.select(
    F.to_json(
        F.struct(*[F.col(c) for c in df.columns])
    ).alias("c4")
)

df1.show(truncate=False)
#+--------------------------+
#|c4                        |
#+--------------------------+
#|{"c1":"v","c2":3,"c3":"a"}|
#|{"c1":"d","c2":2,"c3":"b"}|
#|{"c1":"q","c2":9,"c3":"c"}|
#+--------------------------+
```

---

##### EDIT

If you want a MapType column use `create_map` function:

```
from itertools import chain

df1 = df.select(
    F.create_map(
        *list(chain(*[[F.lit(c), F.col(c)] for c in df.columns]))
    ).alias("c4")
)

#+---------------------------+
#|c4                         |
#+---------------------------+
#|{c1 -> v, c2 -> 3, c3 -> a}|
#|{c1 -> d, c2 -> 2, c3 -> b}|
#|{c1 -> q, c2 -> 9, c3 -> c}|
#+---------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Is there a way to keep the type of values as what it was?

Comment: @AminTabatabaei No, you can't have `MapType` with different types for the values.

Answer (score 0):

You asked specifically for `MapType`, but if you want to support different types of values, `StructType` might also be an alternative:

```py
df_struct = df.select(
    F.struct(
        [F.col(c) for c in df.columns]
    ).alias("c4")
)

df_struct.show()
# +---------+
# |       c4|
# +---------+
# |{v, 3, a}|
# |{d, 2, b}|
# |{q, 9, c}|
# +---------+

df_struct.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- c4: struct (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- c1: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- c2: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- c3: string (nullable = true)
```